# Having trouble optimizing MySQL query with GROUP BY ... HAVING

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to optimize *quickly* optimize the search functionality of some outdated forum software written in PHP.  I've got my work down to a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT thread.threadid
FROM thread AS thread
INNER JOIN word AS word ON (word.title LIKE 'word1' OR word.title LIKE 'word2')
INNER JOIN postindex AS postindex ON (postindex.wordid = word.wordid)
INNER JOIN post AS postquery ON (postquery.postid = postindex.postid)
WHERE thread.threadid = postquery.threadid
GROUP BY thread.threadid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word.wordid) = 2
LIMIT 25;
```

`word1` and `word2` are examples; there could be any number of words.  The number at the very end of the query is the total number of words.  The idea is that a thread most contain all words in the search query, spread out over any number of posts.

This query often exceeds 60 seconds with only two words, and times out.  I'm stumped; I can't figure out how to further optimize this horrid search engine.

As far as I can tell, everything is indexed properly, and I've run `ANALYZE` recently.  Most of the database is running on InnoDB.  Here's the output of `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys                                                                          | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | word      | range  | PRIMARY,title                                                                          | title   | 150     | NULL                         |    2 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | postindex | ref    | wordid,temp_ix                                                                         | temp_ix | 4       | database1.word.wordid        |    3 | Using index condition                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | postquery | eq_ref | PRIMARY,threadid,showthread                                                            | PRIMARY | 4       | database1.postindex.postid   |    1 | NULL                                                      |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | thread    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,forumid,postuserid,pollid,title,lastpost,dateline,prefixid,tweeted,firstpostid | PRIMARY | 4       | database1.postquery.threadid |    1 | Using index                                               |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Update

`LIMIT 25` doesn't seem to be helping much.  It shaves off maybe second from a query that normally returns hundreds of results.

### Clarification

The part that's slowing down MySQL is the `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` bit.  With `GROUP BY`, the `LIMIT` is pretty much useless for improving performance.  Without `GROUP BY`, and as long as the `LIMIT` remains, the queries are quite speedy.

### SQL Info

Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE postindex;`:

```
CREATE TABLE `postindex` (
  `wordid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `postid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `intitle` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `wordid` (`wordid`,`postid`),
  KEY `temp_ix` (`wordid`),
  KEY `postid` (`postid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I didn't make the table, so I have no idea why there's a duplicate index on wordid; however, I'm not willing to delete it, since this is ancient, fickle software.

Comment: This looks dirty, very dirty: "INNER JOIN word AS word ON (word.title LIKE 'word1' OR word.title LIKE 'word2')"

Comment: @PieterB Regarding `word AS word`: The first `word` isn't guaranteed to be `word`; it might have a prefix.  This query was generated by PHP.

Comment: There is an index on word.title.  It's collated as utf8_swedish_ci, I believe (it was imported from a database that used latin1_swedish_ci).  Normalizing the strings in PHP and using equality instead of `LIKE` would probably help.

Comment: The problem is with the "LIKE" no amount of indexing will make that much faster and as far as I can tell, someone correct me if I'm wrong INNODB also doesn't support full text search.

Comment: @PieterB We're using 5.6; InnoDB supports full-text search starting with 5.6.

Comment: Also, it's the `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` that slows down the query.  If I omit that, it's quite speedy.  There's a catch, though: for it to be fast, there has to be a `LIMIT`.

Comment: Does the `LIKE` condition contain (or may contain) wildcards: `LIKE 'word%'` ?

Comment: @ypercube No, they're completely escaped.  However, the strings in the database are not necessarily normalized; for example, some are mixed case.

Comment: I've added a clarification that should be helpful; see bottom of question.

Comment: Compound indexes on `postindex (postid, wordid)` and `postindex (wordid, postid)` would help. Can you provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE postindex;` output?

Comment: @ypercube Added to original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try several rewrites and compare execution plan and times.

Using 2 `EXISTS` subqueries (one for each word to be checked):

```sql
SELECT t.threadid
FROM thread AS t
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM post AS p
          JOIN postindex AS pi
            ON pi.postid = p.postid
          JOIN word AS w
            ON pi.wordid = w.wordid
        WHERE w.title = 'word1'
          AND t.threadid = p.threadid
      )
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM post AS p
          JOIN postindex AS pi
            ON pi.postid = p.postid
          JOIN word AS w
            ON pi.wordid = w.wordid
        WHERE w.title = 'word2'
          AND t.threadid = p.threadid
      ) ;
```

Using one `EXISTS` subquery:

```sql
SELECT t.threadid
FROM thread AS t
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM post AS p1
          JOIN postindex AS pi1
            ON  pi1.postid = p1.postid
          JOIN word AS w1
            ON  w1.wordid = pi1.wordid
            AND w1.title = 'word1'

          JOIN post AS p2
            ON  p2.threadid = p1.threadid
          JOIN postindex AS pi2
            ON  pi2.postid = p2.postid
          JOIN word AS w2
            ON  w2.wordid = pi2.wordid
            AND w2.title = 'word2'

        WHERE t.threadid = p1.threadid
          AND t.threadid = p2.threadid
      ) ;
```

A single query with many joins and `GROUP BY` only to remove the duplicate `threadid`:

```sql
SELECT t.threadid
FROM thread AS t

  JOIN post AS p1
    ON  p1.threadid = t.threadid
  JOIN postindex AS pi1
    ON  pi1.postid = p1.postid
  JOIN word AS w1
    ON  w1.wordid = pi1.wordid
    AND w1.title = 'word1'

  JOIN post AS p2
    ON  p1.threadid = t.threadid
  JOIN postindex AS pi2
    ON  pi2.postid = p2.postid
  JOIN word AS w2
    ON  w2.wordid = pi2.wordid
    AND w2.title = 'word2'

WHERE p1.threadid = p2.threadid        -- this line is redundant
GROUP BY t.threadid ;
```

Comment: This seems to do very well on queries with a lot of results (it takes around a second), but it struggles on queries with few results.  It seems as though the fewer results there are, the slower it goes.  For a query with a single result, it took 42.67 seconds.

Comment: Have you added the `postindex (postid, wordid)` and `postindex (wordid, postid)` indexes?

Comment: Not `postid, wordid`, since it wasn't applicable before.  I'll try that and get back to you.  There are about 12M rows, so it'll take a few minutes.  This is definitely more efficient under normal circumstances, though.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/c4cf69aa38e90b0c5d4f `EXPLAIN` for the first query, which seems to be the easiest to generate using PHP.  Index `postindex (postid, wordid)` is not used; from what I can tell, it's not applicable.  For the last example, you could replace `GROUP BY ...` with `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Here's the query that I ended up using: [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/c4cf69aa38e90b0c5d4f#file-query-sql)  It's almost identical to your first example, but I moved `w.title = '...'` to the `ON` bit for added performance.

Answer (score 0):

I start by creating temporary table, and store distinct (thread.threadid, word.wordid) that match your search. Then select thread.threadid where count() = number of searched words.

Comment: According to `EXPLAIN`, MySQL is creating a temporary table.  I don't think doing so explicitly will speed it up.  Could you provide an example query?